# duplicating click events happening on page to another page

Tags: php, .htaccess, onclick, redirect, url-masking

i have a page say **www.example.com**. it consists of some results(like Google results, these results are injected by me by requesting a third party resource into **example.com**). on clicking one of them it will redirect to some url(say **www.trackclicks.com/some.php**) which tracks the referrer(on which the click event happening) in this case it is **www.example.com**

My requirement is i have to show **www.trackclicks.com/some.php** that click event happened on my page say **mysite.com** but not on **www.example.com** even though it happens on it(i have to mask it).

i never came across of this type of requirement, so i haven't tried anything. i used .htaccess to redirect the pages but not sure i can use them for diverting click events.

**MY thought to do this:**

i will create a page say **cach.php** on mysite.com and redirect the www.trackclicks.com/some.php from my site's page and click the www.trackclicks.com/some.php using javascript.

so the actual reult url on example.com will be like this

www.mysite.com/catch.php?rd="www.trackclicks.com/some.php"

then using javascript i will click it from mysite/cach.php.

Comment: i my self given weird expression when i heard it for first time.. go through it couple of times, if you don't understand it then let me know. will explain you clearly.

Comment: Do you need to hide your tracking link and show (in window.status) your destination link?

Comment: i edited the question hope you will get it now

Comment: I'm writing an answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was writing an example code, but I found [this tutorial](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/target_url_hiding.php) that works great for you. You can mask your url changing `window.status` or handling `location.href`.

Comment: this was i said in my thought see question.. i am going to implement this tomorrow. i redirect to cach.php and redirect the link from there.